# IE compatible DIV form submit button?

Tags: php, javascript, html, internet-explorer

My form is working great with all browsers apart from IE8 and lower. It's so frustrating and I don't know the best way to resolve it?

```
<div class="nextbutton" onclick="checkstep();">Okay, All Done Here &raquo;</div>
```

Why isn't this doing anything? This is the JS below. It's like the button when clicked on does absolutely nothing. It doesn't even acknowledge that it's been pressed. Is it the button code above that's the problem do you think? Any help would be really greatly appreciated!

```
function setgender(genderval) {


document.getElementById('male').checked = false;
document.getElementById('female').checked = false;
document.getElementById('notsay').checked = false;

document.getElementById(genderval).checked = true;

document.getElementById('genderS').value = genderval;

}

function checkstep() {



document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML = "";

var step1doc = document.step1;

var jobtitle = step1.jobtitle.value;
var companyname = step1.companyname.value;
var nearestcity = step1.nearestcity.value;
var industry = step1.industry.value;
var country = step1.country.value;
var brief = step1.brief.value;
var month = step1.month.value;
var day = step1.day.value;
var birthyear = step1.birthyear.value;
var gender = document.getElementById('genderS').value;

var error = '0';

var e_jobtitle = '0';
var e_companyname = '0';
var e_nearestcity = '0';
var e_industry = '0';
var e_country = '0';
var e_brief = '0';
var e_month = '0';
var e_day = '0';
var e_birthyear = '0';
var e_gender = '0';

if ( jobtitle == '' ) { e_jobtitle = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_jobtitle = '0'; }
if ( companyname == '' ) { e_companyname = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_companyname = '0'; }
if ( nearestcity == '' ) { e_nearestcity = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_nearestcity = '0'; }
if ( industry == '0' ) { e_industry = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_industry = '0'; }
if ( country == '0' ) { e_country = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_country = '0'; }
if ( brief == '' ) { e_brief = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_brief = '0'; }
if ( month == '0' ) { e_month = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_month = '0'; }
if ( day == '0' ) { e_day = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_day = '0'; }
if ( birthyear == '0' ) { e_birthyear = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_birthyear = '0'; }
if ( gender == '0' ) { e_gender = '1'; error = '1'; } else { e_gender = '0'; }

var setname = '';

if ( e_jobtitle == '1' ) {
    setname = "Your Job Title";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "Please fill in <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}
if ( e_companyname == '1' ) {
    setname = "Company Name";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "Please fill in <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}
if ( e_nearestcity == '1' ) {
    setname = "Your Nearest City";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "Please fill in <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}
if ( e_industry == '1' ) {
    setname = "Industry";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "You must set your <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}
if ( e_country == '1' ) {
    setname = "Country";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "You must set your <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}
if ( e_brief == '1' ) {
    setname = "Brief";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "You must set a <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}
if ( e_gender == '1' ) {
    setname = "Gender";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "You must choose <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}
if ( ( e_month == '1' ) || ( e_day == '1' ) || ( e_birthyear == '1' ) ) {
    setname = "Birth Day";
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "You must set your <font color=red>"+setname+"</font><br>";
} else {}

if ( error == '0' ) {

document.getElementById('full_content').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('loading_content').style.display = "";

setTimeout(getstep2, 2000);

} else { 
    document.getElementById('resultstep').innerHTML += "<br><br>";
}



}


function getstep2() {



    var updateStep1AR;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        updateStep1AR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            updateStep1AR = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                updateStep1AR = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    updateStep1AR.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(updateStep1AR.readyState == 4){
var updrez = updateStep1AR.responseText;




        }
    }


var upd_jobtitle = step1.jobtitle.value.replace(/&/g, "222111");
var upd_companyname = step1.companyname.value.replace(/&/g, "222111");
var upd_nearestcity = step1.nearestcity.value.replace(/&/g, "222111");
var upd_industry = step1.industry.value;
var upd_country = step1.country.value;
var upd_brief = step1.brief.value.replace(/&/g, "222111");
var upd_genderS = step1.genderS.value;
var upd_month = step1.month.value;
var upd_day = step1.day.value;
var upd_birthyear = step1.birthyear.value;

    var queryString = "jobtitle="+upd_jobtitle+"&companyname="+upd_companyname+"&nearestcity="+upd_nearestcity+"&industry="+upd_industry+"&country="+upd_country+"&brief="+upd_brief+"&genderS="+upd_genderS+"&month="+upd_month+"&day="+upd_day+"&year="+upd_birthyear;

    updnocache = Math.random();
    updateStep1AR.open("GET", "/ajax/update_profile.php?" + queryString + "&nocache=" + updnocache, true);
    updateStep1AR.send(null); 





document.getElementById('full_content').innerHTML = document.getElementById('step2page').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('step2page').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('full_content').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('loading_content').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Why do you use a div as a button? Use a button!

Comment: @epascarello An *onclick* on a *div* should work... it's not because IE does not follow standards and *click* does not work in some weird cases that everybody should use only *button* to have something clickable...

Comment: Do you see any error (bottom left), is the *div* floated (see the link above given by @Zenith)

Comment: @ring0 Have you thought about accessibility, it is impossible for me to use keyboard navigation to click on that div element. Not everyone uses a mouse to navigate a page.

Comment: @epascarello Accessibility, indeed. It all depends on the application... hard to say based on the question. But anyway , if *onclick* is supposed to work on a *div*, it has to. IE is/was pain, mainly CSS but it has also some JS peculiarities that are annoying..

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it in jQuery? Its designed for cross-browser compatibility and would be very simple to achieve. Alternatively, if you're sure you want to use javascript, instead of using a div, try using an  element:

```
<a href="javascript:checkstep()">Okay, All Done Here</a>
```

In jQuery, you could have the following:

```
<div id="nextStepButton">Okay, All Done Here</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#nextStepButton').click(function(){
    checkstep();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work with either of those solutions. I think it must be the javascript rather than the button :(

Comment: Do you have an address I have have a look at?